Is there a way to print an angular page to pdf without showing the page itself?
I am trying to build a way to take an html document, possibly built by an angular component and print it to pdf without it being shown to the user. I have no idea if that is possible.
The optimal solution would have the component render the page, but not display it. That document gets passed to a service, which then "prints" the document to pdf and downloads it for the user. I am currently using angular 17 to do this work.
I have tried creating a component and rendering it in an "invisible" div, but that doe snot seem to work. I have also tried rendering a component by passing it to another component, but I was not successful in that either. I am not sure if/how to send a component to another component.

If you want to control which components are displayed on a printed page, you can use the media query:
@media screen {
  .print-component {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .print-component {
    display: block;
  }
}


You can also do more complex style rules which are only applied when it's to be printed.
